# my canvas is null the browser is blank

Tags: javascript, html

I write a little web game with html5 plus javascript. I create two file ,one is htmml5 file another is javascript file.Here i come into a problem is that my canvas is null.
here is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>frogger</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="gamecontrol.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="painting" width="600" height="600" tabindex="0" style="border: solid blue 1px">

</canvas>​

</body>
</html>
```

my javascript code

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("painting");
    canvas.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {           //listen the key event
        doKeyDown(e);
    });

    var context2D = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var lifecount = 3;     // frogger has three life values
    var score = 0;         // when frogger accross a line successfully it will get 10 points

    var pic = new Image();
    var pic1=new Image();
    var picpipe1 = new Image();      // pipe image
    var picpipe2 = new Image();
    var spider1 = new Image();
    var spider2 = new Image();
    var gresp1 = new Image();
    var gresp2 = new Image();
    var rocket = new Image();
    var car = new Image();
    var wheel = new Image();
    var car1 = new Image();
    var car2 = new Image();

    //the coordinates
    var X=0,Y=110;
    var spider1X= 0,spider1Y=140;
    var spider2X= 0,spider2Y=230;
    var X1=300,Y1=450;     // frogger's ordinary coordinate
    var pipe1X=0,pipe1Y=170;
    var pipe2X= 0,pipe2Y=200;
    var rocketX = 0,rocketY=300;
    var carX = 0, carY =330;
    var wheelX= 0,wheelY=360;
    var car1X= 0, car1Y=390;
    var car2X= 0, car2Y=420;

    //load image
    pic.src = "pipe.jpg";
    pic1.src = "qingwa.jpg";
    picpipe1.src = "pipe.jpg";
    picpipe2.src = "pipe.jpg";
    spider1.src="spider.jpg";
    spider2.src="spider.jpg";
    gresp1.src = "gresp.jpg";
    gresp2.src = "gresp.jpg";

    rocket.src = "rocket.jpg";
    car.src = "car.jpg";
    wheel.src = "wheel.jpg";
    car1.src = "car1.jpg";
    car2.src = "car2.jpg";

    function drawline()
    {
    context2D.moveTo(0,100);
    context2D.lineTo(35,100);
    context2D.lineTo(35,60);
    context2D.lineTo(85,60);
    context2D.lineTo(85,100);
    context2D.lineTo(155,100);
    context2D.lineTo(155,60);
    context2D.lineTo(205,60);
    context2D.lineTo(205,100);
    context2D.lineTo(275,100);
    context2D.lineTo(275,60);
    context2D.lineTo(325,60);
    context2D.lineTo(325,100);
    context2D.lineTo(395,100);
    context2D.lineTo(395,60);
    context2D.lineTo(445,60);
    context2D.lineTo(445,100);
    context2D.lineTo(515,100);
    context2D.lineTo(515,60);
    context2D.lineTo(565,60);
    context2D.lineTo(565,100);
    context2D.lineTo(600,100);


    context2D.stroke();
    }
    function doKeyDown(e)
    {
        switch (e.keyCode)
        {
        // the up key
            case 38:
            Y1 = Y1 - 45;
            break;
        //the down key
            case 40:
            Y1 = Y1 + 45;
            break;

        //the left key
            case 37:
            X1 = X1 - 10;
            break;

        //the right key
            case 39:
            X1 = X1 + 10;
            break;

        }
    }

    function drawfrogger()
    {

        context2D.drawImage(pic1,X1,Y1);
    }
    function draw()
    {

        context2D.clearRect(0,0,600,600);
        context2D.save();

        context2D.drawImage(gresp1,0,250);
        context2D.drawImage(gresp2,0,450);
        context2D.drawImage(pic,X,Y);
        context2D.drawImage(picpipe1,pipe1X,pipe1Y);
        context2D.drawImage(picpipe2,pipe2X,pipe2Y);
        context2D.drawImage(spider1,spider1X,spider1Y);
        context2D.drawImage(spider2,spider2X,spider2Y);
        context2D.drawImage(rocket,rocketX,rocketY);
        context2D.drawImage(car,carX,carY);
        context2D.drawImage(wheel,wheelX,wheelY);
        context2D.drawImage(car1,car1X,car1Y);
        context2D.drawImage(car2,car2X,car2Y);
        //some text about score line
        context2D.font = "40pt Calibri";
        context2D.fillStyle = "blue";
        context2D.fillText('SCORE:',0,550);

        context2D.font = "40pt Calibri";
        context2D.fillStyle = "red";
        context2D.fillText(score,180,550);

        X = X + 100;
        pipe1X = pipe1X + 60;
        pipe2X = pipe2X + 80;
        spider1X = spider1X + 70;
        spider2X = spider2X + 55;
        rocketX = rocketX + 35;
        carX = carX + 25;
        wheelX = wheelX + 55;
        car1X =car1X + 45;
        car2X = car2X + 38;

        drawfrogger();
        drawline();
        context2D.restore(); //绘制结束以后，恢复画笔状态
        if(X>600)
            X = 0;
        if(pipe1X > 600)
            pipe1X = 0;

        if(pipe2X > 600)
        pipe2X = 0;

        if(spider1X > 600)
        spider1X = 0;

        if(spider2X > 600)
        spider2X = 0;

        if(rocketX > 600)
        rocketX = 0;

        if(carX > 600)
        carX = 0;

        if(wheelX > 600)
        wheelX = 0;

        if(car1X > 600)
        car1X = 0;

        if(car2X > 600)
        car2X = 0;
    }

    //collision test

    function collision()
    {
        switch(Y1)
        {
            case 405:
                score = 10;
                break;

            case 360:
                score = 20;
                break;
            case 315:
                score = 30;
                break;
            case 270:
                score = 40;
                break;
            case 225:
                score = 50;
                break;


        }

    }


    function run()
    {
        draw();
        collision()

    }
    setInterval(run, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that you are attempting to access the canvas element before the DOM is ready.

Making the following modification to your JS should sovle it.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("painting");
    ...
    ... 
    car2.src = "car2.jpg";
};

function drawline() {
    ...
}

... rest of the functions
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is the javascript file doesnt have function but direct code... so its executed at place where js file is included... at that point you dont have canvas in your DOM..

solution is in js use

```
function myfun(){
var canvas = document.getElementById("painting");
    canvas.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {           //listen the key event
        doKeyDown(e);
    });

    var context2D = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var lifecount = 3;     // frogger has three life values
    var score = 0;         // when frogger accross a line successfully it will get 10 points
... //remaining code

}
```

and then in HTML update body tag to

```
<body onload="myfun()">
```